# drop down list selection with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a drop down list with year and make
if clients choose each option in year , they will get options in make with the same class
for example: if they choose year = 2015 (value= 65399), the drop down list of make will create a list with class="65399"
It doesn't work with my code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Learning jQuery</title>
 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

 </head>

 <body>
 <form>


   <select class="mn-year form-select" id="edit-mn-year" name="mn-year">
   <option value="" selected="selected">- Choose Year -</option>
   <option value="65399">2015</option>
   <option value="56040">2014</option>
   <option value="55580">2013</option>
   <option value="55572">2012</option>
   
   </select>
   <select class="mn-make form-select" id="edit-mn-make" name="mn-make">
   <option value="" selected="selected">- Choose Make -</option>
   <option class="65399" value="65417">Chevrolet</option>
   <option class="65399" value="65493">Ford</option>
   <option class="65399" value="65403">GMC</option>
   <option class="65399" value="65472">Jeep</option>
   <option class="65399" value="65889">Ram</option>
   <option class="65399" value="65488">Scion</option>
   <option class="65399" value="65516">Toyota</option>
   <option class="56040" value="63128">Chevrolet</option>
   <option class="56040" value="65140">Ford</option>
   <option class="56040" value="63121">GMC</option>

   </select>

</form>



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 var year = $("#edit-mn-make").children('option').map(function() {
        return {
            "value": this.value,
           
        }
    })

    var make = $("#edit-mn-make").children('option').map(function() {
        return {
            "value": this.value,
   "class": this.class,
            "option": "<option value='" + this.value+ "'>" + this.text + "</option>"
        }
    })
 
  $("#edit-mn-year").change(function() {
        $("#edit-mn-make").children('option').remove();
        var addoptarr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
   for(j = 0; j< make.length; j++){
    if ( year[i].value == make[j].class) {
                addoptarr.push(make[i].option);
                }
   }
            
        }
        $("#edit-mn-make").html(addoptarr.join(''))
    }).change();
        
   
})

</script>








 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are overcomplicating it a bit. I made a working fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/79o6w2nh/

My implementation just hides everything and then shows the options that have the year as a data attribute.:

```
$("#edit-mn-year").change(function(){
    $("#edit-mn-make").children().hide();
    $("#edit-mn-make").children('*[data-year="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show();
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mattocream/0tkod0tb/. I try to make this list longer. the problem is that when I choose year 2012, I coudn't see any option in make list until I push up/down on my keyboard, and I just see one option in it. How to solve this problem. Thanks martin

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  

$("#edit-mn-year").change(function(){  
    var cls=$(this).val();

    $("#edit-mn-make ."+cls).attr('selected','selected');
    });

  });
```